# Limit of Implicitly Defined Function (Follow up)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

> Is there a method such that one can determine the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}, n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ for an implicitly defined function, defined near the origin  - such as $2x^3-3x^2+2y^3+3y^2-y=0$ - given that the limit actually exists?

This post serves as a follow up to an answer given my previous question (see [Limit of Implicitly Defined Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050555/limit-of-implicitly-defined-function)).

Richard P came with the astute observation that given the implicit function theorem tells us $y$ can be represented as a function of $f$, i.e. $y=f(x)$, one may use the definition of single variable differentiation and consider it at $x=0$, for:

\begin{align}
f'(0)&=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} \\ &=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}
\end{align}
as $f(0,0)=0$. Thus, all that one has to do is to use implicit differentiation, with respect to $x$, on $f(x,y)=0$, rearrange and then let $x \to 0$ to determine $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

If we know the given limit exists then, as $\;f(x)\;$ is assumed differentiable, it *must* be that $\;f(0)=0\;$ , so we can apply l'Hospitla's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$$

But

$$2x^3-3x^2+2y^3+3y^2-y=0\implies6x^2-6x+(6y^2+6y-1)y'=0\implies$$

$$\implies f'(x)=y'=\frac{6x-6x^2}{6y^2+6y-1}$$

**if** the last expression's denominador isn't zero, and if $\;6y^2+6y\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1\;$, then our limit is zero. Otherwise we may need more conditions to be sure of anything.

Comment: Great! Now, is it possible to go further and consider say $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ using this approach, or do we need more conditions?

Comment: @realClearAnalysis, I think we may need more conditions, for example: by the same reason as above, we can "begin" using l'Hospital, but then we need to know what to do, if anything at all, with $\;\frac{f'(x)}{2x}\;$ ...I'm not completely sure, but I think in the most general case we can't say much more than this.